# Wrapped $.ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this, jsonp

$.ajax is wrapped into new 'get' function.

If there is only one 'get' invoke in js file, it is fine. 
But 2 calls in row fail.

More precise,
first call fails with "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined",
second one is successful, BUT in success function it has data for first 'get' invoke.

As I can guess, there is some issue with 'this'/context. Could you explain it to me?

```
    (function() {
        "use strict";

        function get(url, success, error) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: 'process',
                url: url,
                success: success,
                error: error
            });
        }

        get('XXX',
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("SUCCESS PING 1");
                console.log(data);
            },
            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("ERROR PIND 1");
            });

        get('YYY',
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("SUCCESS PING 2");
                console.log(data);
            },
            function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("ERROR PING 2");
            });
    })();

/*
===========================================
===============console=====================
===========================================
1. ERROR PIND WAR
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at db?callback=process&_=1485184752755:1
3. SUCCESS PING DB
4. Object {data for first call here}
*/
```

Comment: perhaps you should pass in a different jsonp callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, It's better **do NOT specify a custom callback name** ('jsonpCallback' parameter)

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> jsonpCallback Type: String or Function() Specify the callback function
>   name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the
>   random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let
>   jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the
>   requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to
>   specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of
>   GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this
>   setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is set to the return
>   value of that function.

The thing is, that jQuery creates global function in window object with specified name and later remove it.
I didn't manage to get full picture of what going on inside jQuery library, but
the issue is definitely caused by fact that it tries to call function that just has been removed.

*Removing  jsonpCallback param resolve an issue*